# QtCreator does not start up

Tags: qt-creator

I have installed Qt Creator using Ubuntu Software Center but when I try to run it nothing happens. There is no error message, no new process, no new window.

Comment: run it from terminal `qtcreator`

Comment: Then I get: Illegal instruction (core dumped). Is there any way to examine what this is caused by ?

Comment: I used `file /usr/bin/qtcreator` to see if it is 32-bit and it is.

Comment: try to reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall qtcreator`

Comment: I tried reinstalling qtcreator and even Ubuntu. It does not change anything.

Comment: Do you use VirtualBox ? Case yes, disable 3d acceleration

Answer (score 1):

You may be running QtCreator on an old CPU that's missing SSE2 instructions, hence the "illegal instruction" message. See this question on archlinux:https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/34228 .

However, I don't know if it possible to recompile recent QtCreator (2.7) so that it doesn't use SSE2 instructions.